# Create New Python 3 notebook in Colaboratory Fails with error message

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have recently started to use Colaboratory and I  am trying to create a new notebook.

But when I try to Open new notebook (New Python 3 notebook) if fails with this error message:

Notebook loading error
There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.
https://drive.google.com/drive/?action=locate&id=1Hfx8Cl68kYnKZu90U5TADO0XqKsBq_fw&authuser=0
[object Object]
Error: [object Object]
    at d (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_20180222_085323-RC01_186629092:1135:347)
    at Object.next (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_20180222_085323-RC01_186629092:1135:493)
    at b (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_20180222_085323-RC01_186629092:522:42)
    at

I saved a copy of the Welcome to Colaboratory notebook to my Google Drive.
When I try to Open Drive notebook, and select the notebook copy it crashes with the same error message above.

What else can I try to create a new notebook?

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using? If Chrome, does the error persist in an incognito window? (i.e., with extensions disabled?)

Comment: @Bob Smith

Hi,

I had given up on trying to open a new Colaboratory/Jupiter notebook in the Chrome browser.

Then I tried to open a new notebook in the Firefox browser and it worked.

Following your instructions, in the Chrome browser upper right menu I selected New incognito window and was able to open a new notebook in the Chrome browser.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share which extension is at issue? It would be helpful for other folks to know for diagnosis, I suspect.

Comment: @Bob Smith In the chrome browser I clicked the upper right menu icon then selected New incognito window. I did not make any new extension settings.

Comment: Sure, but what extensions do you have installed? Does disabling one in particular fix the issue? (Incognito is just a convenient shortcut to disable all extensions.)

Comment: The same issue happened when I deleted my notebook. But this doesn't look like a persistent issue to me. I gave it some time and then everything loaded properly. Looks like it wasn't a chrome plugin after all.

Comment: In my case it was uBlock Origin... Had to switch to Adblock Plus unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

pause your adblock extension for the colab page and it will work. Ad blocks may block some js file

Comment: I didn't install any adblock extension for my browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to active All cookies on Cookie Control in your browser:

[image: Active Cookies in broswer]